# Which one is grammatically correct:

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

Which sentence is grammatically correct:

The statute stated that,"The "vegan..."

or

The statue stated,"The vegan.."

Do you add the word that or not?

Comment: Does anyone know which one would be correct grammatically?

Answer (score 1):

Words like *state* and *say* take two similar but not identical structures as their object:

They can take a quoted string, the words uttered: *He said "I won't go".* This is sometimes called "direct speech".

Or they can take a clause introduced by *that*. This is "reported speech", and pronouns are substituted, and the verb are backshifted: *He said that he wouldn't go.*

*That* can often be omitted in reported speech; but it can never be inserted in direct speech.